# change title in a dispersion plot created with yellowbrick

Tags: matplotlib, yellowbrick

I would like to change the title of the dispersion plot created using yellowbrick:

I use the following code:

```
wl = []
with open('my-text.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
   wl = f.read().split()
   
topics = ['δὲ']
plt.figure(figsize=(16,.5))
visualizer = DispersionPlot(topics)
visualizer.fit([poll_wl])
visualizer.show()
```

The plot created has the title "Lexical Dispersion Plot". I would like to use a customized title.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `figure` from visalizer and then set the title text of the only `axes` object like this:

```
visualizer.fig.get_axes()[0].title.set_text("My Title")
```

The same can be done with `visualizer.set_title("My Title")` although it appears to not be explicitely included in the [docs](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/index.html).

Example (from [the docs](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/text/dispersion.html#dispersion-plot)):

```
from yellowbrick.text import DispersionPlot
from yellowbrick.datasets import load_hobbies

corpus = load_hobbies()
text = [doc.split() for doc in corpus.data]
target_words = ['Game', 'player', 'score', 'oil', 'Man']
visualizer = DispersionPlot(target_words)
visualizer.fit(text)
visualizer.show()

visualizer.set_title("My Title")
```

[image]